# WSO2 Governance Registry: Cannot add Active Directory user store with certificates

Tags: java, certificate

I'am using wso2 governance registry 5.0.1 and have a problem to add an active directory user store. I succesfully added my certifactes (.crt files) to the JVM's truststore but have this error:

```
[Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:226)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:137)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1613)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2746)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
        at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:101)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext.getContext(LDAPConnectionContext.java:167)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:156)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.<init>(ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.java:85)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.createSecondaryUserStoreManager(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3551)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addSecondaryUserStoreManager(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3607)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserStoreDeploymentManager.deploy(UserStoreDeploymentManager.java:74)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer.deploy(UserStoreConfigurationDeployer.java:164)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1506)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:376)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:203)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1488)
        ... 51 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 57 more
```

I also tried to import manually these certifactes from carbon console (
Home > Configure > KeyStores > Import Certificates To ) 
=> Same problem.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" sounds like one or more of the certificates is issued by an CA that is not trusted.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the CA that issued your certificate, and it is trying to validate it.

I'm assuming this is a client certificate (your software is rare and I have never heard of it before, but this looks pretty standard).  In that case, your application should allow you to specify a trusted CA that issues these, probably in the form of a JKS file.  Make sure that's specified and the CA that issues the client certificates is in there.

A very common mistake people make is specifying the trusted CA list that is used for websites as the trust root for client certificates - you don't want to trust that and your certificates probably don't chain to it.  The root for client certificates is generally a CA that you set up to issue them.